# SHarePoint 2013 site collection through client object model

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am working on a requirement where I need to create a site collection in SharePoint using client side api. I know server side we can do it using self service site creation api. Also I know in case of SharePoint Online , we have Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll that we can use to create site collection However in my case I have a On premise environment  (SharePoint 2013) where I need to create a site collection thru client side api. Can you please let me know if there is any API that I can use for this requirement.

Thanks for any Help you can provide on this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible to do by using the CSOM, on an on-premise environment.

As you mentioned, it is possible on the SPO environment using the library that you listed (Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll).

I'm not sure if this will help, but here is code that could create a site inside of the current site collection:

```
You will also need to add using statements for System.Collections.Generic and System.Text.

// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
// server running SharePoint. 
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

WebCreationInformation creation = new WebCreationInformation(); 
creation.Url = "web1"; 
creation.Title = "Hello web1"; 
Web newWeb = context.Web.Webs.Add(creation); 

// Retrieve the new web information. 
context.Load(newWeb, w => w.Title); 
context.ExecuteQuery(); 

label1.Text = newWeb.Title;
```

This code was taken directly from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179912.aspx

Answer (score 2):

### How to create site collection via SharePoint 2013 Managed CSOM

[Tenant.CreateSite method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.tenant.createsite.aspx) from `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll` assembly is intended for site collection creation:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new site.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <param name="url">rootsite + "/" + managedPath + "/" + sitename: e.g. "https://auto.contoso.com/sites/site1"</param>
    /// <param name="title">site title: e.g. "Test Site"</param>
    /// <param name="owner">site owner: e.g. admin@contoso.com</param>
    /// <param name="template">The site template used to create this new site</param>
    /// <param name="localeId"></param>
    /// <param name="compatibilityLevel"></param>
    /// <param name="storageQuota"></param>
    /// <param name="resourceQuota"></param>
    /// <param name="timeZoneId"></param>
    internal static void CreateSite(ClientContext context, String url, String owner, String title =null, String template = null, uint? localeId = null, int? compatibilityLevel = null, long? storageQuota = null, double? resourceQuota = null, int? timeZoneId = null)
    {
        var tenant = new Tenant(context);

        if (url == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Site Url must be specified");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(owner))
            throw new ArgumentException("Site Owner must be specified");

        var siteCreationProperties = new SiteCreationProperties {Url = url, Owner = owner};
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(template))
            siteCreationProperties.Template = template;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
            siteCreationProperties.Title = title;
        if (localeId.HasValue)
            siteCreationProperties.Lcid = localeId.Value;
        if (compatibilityLevel.HasValue)
            siteCreationProperties.CompatibilityLevel = compatibilityLevel.Value;
        if (storageQuota.HasValue)
            siteCreationProperties.StorageMaximumLevel = storageQuota.Value;
        if (resourceQuota.HasValue)
            siteCreationProperties.UserCodeMaximumLevel = resourceQuota.Value;
        if (timeZoneId.HasValue)
            siteCreationProperties.TimeZoneId = timeZoneId.Value;
        var siteOp = tenant.CreateSite(siteCreationProperties);
        context.Load(siteOp);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

    }




//Usage
const string username = "***@***.onmicrosoft.com";
const string password = "***";
const string tenantAdminUrl = "https://***-admin.sharepoint.com/";
const string newSiteCollUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/finance"
var securedPassword = new SecureString();
foreach (var c in password.ToCharArray()) securedPassword.AppendChar(c);
var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword);


using (var context = new ClientContext(tenantAdminUrl))
{
     context.Credentials = credentials;
     CreateSite(context, newSiteCollUrl,username);   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is available in the April 2014 CU

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/06/09/provisioning-site-collections-using-sp-app-model-in-on-premises-with-just-csom.aspx